# Kernel version not correct on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel

I have this situation:
Ubuntu 16.04;

When I called `uname -a` result is `Linux pi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

The problem is when I want to compile new drivers, the system gives me the error:

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.1.19-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

But when I looked at `/lib/modules/`, I find only version `4.4.38-v7+`.
Maybe someone knows what it can be?

Thanks.

Comment: you tried compiling from source?

Comment: What are you mean? Sorry did not understand?

Comment: How you are installing? You are building it at your own side?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67330/trouble-installing-the-ch340-driver-on-raspbian-wheezy

Comment: I download drivers on the internet, and with manual trying Build the driver with "make". I opened directory and put only make, that's it. Directory located in "Downloads".

Comment: ok. check that link. I guess you are searching files in /lib/modules of your local machine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have kernel-headers installed for the kernel version that you are trying to compile for.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

You have kernel headers for 4.4.38-v7+, but not for your booted kernel of 4.1.19-v7+ (uname -r)

If you don't want to install 4.1.19-v7+ kernel-headers, reboot the system and boot into 4.4.38-v7+, and then try make, and it would compile the module for that particular kernel.